# Assign values to sorted result in SQL

Tags: sql

I have got table like below after sorting in SQL:

```
M_ID
-----
2013/01
2013/02
2013/03
2013/04
2013/05
2013/06
```

Now I want to assign each entries a particular value like below

```
M_ID      Days
--------------
2013/01   20
2013/02   30
2013/03   40
2013/04   50
2013/05   60
2013/06   70
```

So, can you please let me know how to do that in SQL Query?

Comment: And how do you want to determine what the values are for each entry?

Comment: The value will always be LastValue+10 starting at 20?

Comment: What type of SQL are you using? MS SQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like  this (presuming sql-server)?

```
SELECT M_ID,
       Days = (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY M_ID) + 1) * 10
FROM dbo.TableName
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c0f9/3/0)